# CalendarAnything Visualforce: Display on Opportunity page not showing events?

Tags: visualforce, calendar

I'm trying to display a series of recurring events in a CalendarAnything section on the Opportunity page layout. I've gotten the empty calendar anything box itself to display, but not the data within.

Also, would like the calendar to display a default time of day as most Events are in the evening.

Any help is appreciated.

Code:

```
<apex:page showHeader="false"

showChat="false"

standardController="Opportunity"

sidebar="false">

<SLCA2:calendar namespace="SLCA2"

calendar="a0Nj0000002Zmd9EAC,a0Nj0000002ZmdJEAS,a0Nj0000002ZmdOEAS,a0Nj0000002ZmeDEAS,a0Nj0000002ZmeNEAS,a0Nj0000002ZmemEAC,a0Nj0000002ZmffEAC,a0Nj0000002ZmfuEAC,a0Nj0000002ZmfzEAC,a0Nj0000002Zmg9EAC,a0Nj0000002ZmgJEAS,a0Nj0000002ZmhXEAS,a0Nj0000002ZmhrEAC,a0Nj0000002Zmi1EAC"

settings="['l_ds','r_y',
'r_l',
'r_g',
'r_c']"

urlparams="sb=2&url=0&v=w&pv1={!Opportunity.Name}">

</SLCA2:calendar>

</apex:page>
```

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve this problem by removing the "&pv1={!Opportunity.Name}" variable.